# Lindel's theorem for semisimple simply connected G

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $k$ be a field.

$G/k$ be a simply connected semisimple algebraic group.

Let $X/k$ be a smooth affine $k$-scheme.

**Question**: Is every principal $G$ bundle on $X\times {\mathbb A}^1$ a pull back from $X$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In full generality, the answer is no. There are examples of Parimala of non-extended torsors for special orthogonal groups over $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$, see e.g. Amer J. Math. 100 (1978), 913-924, (admittedly the group is not simply-connected in this case). These examples are also discussed in Lam's book "Serre's problem on projective modules". Further examples of a dramatic failure of Serre's problem for anisotropic groups were given by Raghunathan, see Principal bundles on affine space and bundles on the projective line, Math. Ann. 285 (1989), 309-332.

The answer is yes, if you restrict to $k$ being an infinite field, $G$ being an isotropic group (i.e. $G$ should contain a split torus of rank $\geq 1$) and consider only rationally trivial torsors. This can be found as Theorem 3.1 in my paper: Rationally trivial torsors in $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory, J. K-Theory 7 (2011), 541-572 (essentially all the relevant ingredients were in the literature before, but quite scattered; the result is a combination of a general local-global principle for torsors, the results of Raghunathan for torsors on affine spaces, and the extension of Lindel's method by Colliot-Thélène and Ojanguren)

Comment: I just checked that ragunathan's Theorem B in the paper you mentioned has some conditions on G. Does his paper gives rise to simply connected examples?

Comment: Yes. A semisimple simply-connected group with irreducible root system is absolutely almost simple. There are anisotropic simply-connected groups (Spin groups for anisotropic quadratic forms). The second condition is satisfied for Spin groups, because the special orthogonal groups are rational as varieties.

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to look at http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3078. You will see that the answer is in general "no" even if you assume that $k$ is the field of complex numbers.